# "unset" function is called before other lines

Tags: php, session, unset

My question may look weired! "unset" function is called before its line.
My example code is:

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION[$session_key]);
unset($_SESSION[$session_key][$key]);
```

this code give no result, and the session give empty. But when i comment the unset function, it show the session values normal:

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION[$session_key]);
//unset($_SESSION[$session_key][$key]);
```

please can someone help why this occur?

Comment: Of course $session_key & $key are defined and not empty. it's just a sample code not all my code.

Comment: This is in the same source that is invoked in order to set the `$_SESSION` data, isn't it?

Comment: may you explain your question?

Comment: My bet is that the `unset` is ran before you redirect to some other page, effectively removing the data before you have a chance to read it.

Comment: The main function of UNSET is to clear the SESSION DATA.

Comment: I agree with Filip - I don't think this is enough code to understand your problem!

Comment: sorry guys for this complication, but the code is quite complicated. but i found the solution. I moved the tag
[code]<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />[/code]
to the top after <head> directly.